# How to query the name of each section and the number of threads at it using sql query?

Tags: sql, database

I have 2 tables at mysql database the first one contains parts like this:

```
parts       
primary part_name       part_id
0       web                 1
0       graphic             2
1       php                 3
1       asp                 4
2       photoshop           5
2       illustrator         6
1       html                7
```

some of parts are primary like web, graphic. and others are subsections
for example web section contains (php,asp,html) parts
so at primary field there is the id of father part

graphic part contains (photoshop, illustrator) parts.

the other table is for posts;

```
posts           
post_content    post_title    part_id   post_id
anything          any title      3       1
anything          any title      6       2
anything          any title      3       3
anything          any title      3       4
anything          any title      7       5
anything          any title      6       6
anything          any title      4       7
anything          any title      4       8
anything          any title      3       9
```

I want to get a table contains the main parts (primary = 0)
and sum of posts at it

the result should be like this;

```
query result        
count_posts   part_name   part_id
7               web          1
2               graphic      2
```

I tried this:

```
SELECT p.*,count(s.post_id)
FROM part p,post s
where s.part_id = 1
and p.belong = 1
```

but it get results only for one part

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't yet comment on other posts than my own so I'm submiting a new answer.
@StuartLC answer is missing the join between primary parts and subsections.

```
SELECT COUNT(po.post_id) AS count_posts, pa.part_name, pa.part_id
FROM parts pa
  INNER JOIN parts pa2 on pa2.[primary] = pa.part_id
  INNER JOIN posts po on po.part_id = pa2.part_id
WHERE pa.[primary] = 0
GROUP BY pa.part_name, pa.part_id
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/1dd90/3/0

Comment: this is so good. I also want to get empty parts if exists. thank you alot

Comment: @zuhair to get empty parts you just need to modify the query to use `LEFT OUTER JOINS` instead of `INNER JOINS`  see here [http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/ded79/3/0](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/ded79/3/0)